# How to check validity of a Boolean Expression in z3py given in string format

Tags: string, boolean-expression, z3py

I have a boolean formula such as `(i_0 | i_1) ^ ((~i_0) & (~i_1))`. And I want to check its validity using z3 python.

The main challenge that I'm facing is How to convert this string into a formula in z3 format?

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To check validity of a formula, assert its negation and see if it's `unsat`. If the negation is unsatisfiable, that'd mean that your formula is valid for all assignments, i.e., it's a tautology.

Here's how you do that for your formula in z3py:

```py
from z3 import *

i_0, i_1 = Bools('i_0 i_1')

s = Solver()
s.add(Not(Xor(Or(i_0, i_1), And(Not(i_0), Not(i_1)))))

print(s.check())
```

Note the outermost `Not` as we add the formula to the solver, to negate it. Inside the `Not` is a straightforward encoding of your formula, using `And`, `Or`, `Xor`, and `Not` functions.

When I run this, I get:

```
unsat
```

which means that your original formula is a tautology.

**Note** If your question is about how to take the input as a "string" and turn it into a z3Py formula automatically, then there's really no "out-of-the-box" way of doing that; as your string can have arbitrary conventions, operators, parentheses etc. But that is the typical parsing problem, i.e., converting text input to the function calls needed to run in z3py; and should be tagged as such.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution. Unfortunately, my main problem is to convert string to z3 acceptable format as you pointed out in your note.

Can you suggest to me some links where I can read about building parsers for such a problem? Will be a great help.

Comment: Lex/Yacc are the traditional tools to build such parsers. For Python, you probably want to use ply: https://ply.readthedocs.io/en/latest/